# Color Gradients With ggplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have some geographic x,y,z data which I plot as follows

```
p<-ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z),data=my_data)
```

I then apply a gradient

```
p<-p + scale_fill_gradient(low = "pink", high = "green")
```

And then tile and display the data

```
p<-p + geom_tile()
p
```

This works and gives the following:

[image]

One would think then, that I could replace the `scale_fill_gradient()` call with any number of other options such as

```
p<-p + scale_color_hue()
p<-p + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("#E5F5F9","#99D8C9","#2CA25F"))
p<-p + scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7))
p<-p + scale_colour_brewer()
```

would work.

But they don't, all I get is a gradient of blue.

Any thoughts as to why this might be, and how I can generate lots of happy colours?

Comment: To expand on what joran said, if you replace the word `color` in all of those examples with the word `fill` I think you'll find you can generate all your "happy colours"

Comment: Thanks @Justin, this seems to be changing the outline color of my geom_tiles... so I need a way to map the `scale_colour` commands to the tile's fill property...

Comment: Thanks @joran, that's so obvious in retrospect, but it's just affecting the outline of the cells, as in the comment I left Justin. I'll upload a picture.

Comment: Erm, use `scale_colour_*` to change the color and `scale_fill_*` to change the fill.

Comment: @joran, I got things working off of your comments. Could you please write them up as an answer? If it seems in complete, I'll edit it appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two versions of these scale functions, one for `colour` and one for `fill`. You just needed to use the `fill` versions, i.e. `scale_fill_hue`, etc.